# Converting jupyter notebook file to html (with Table of Contents)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am trying to convert my jupyter notebook file to html and include the table of contents (from jupyter_contrib_nbextensions).

I am running the following code: jupyter nbconvert --to html_toc test.ipynb

I have also tried using the in built converter by trying to download the file as a HTML + toc

The HTML files are being created, but the table of contents is missing?

I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while and tried various searches online for similar problems but to no avail (see below links that appear to be related to my issue).

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1568
[How to set the argument "--template toc2" through nbconvert API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658289/how-to-set-the-argument-template-toc2-through-nbconvert-api).

I'm currently running the following:

jupyter core : 5.3.0
notebook : 6.5.4
ipython : 8.12.0
ipykernel : 6.19.2
jupyter client : 6.1.12
nbconvert : 7.4